# Shuffle function for list in a list

Tags: python, list, random, shuffle

Trying to append two lists and shuffle elements of both lists simultaneously with one enumerate function

I am using two functions:

1. Appending list_b to list_a
2. Shuffling list_a and giving using enumerate function to do indexing.

In addition, I also want to shuffle elements of list_b within the new shuffled list_a and use same enumerate function to index items of both lists in a same number sequence. Below is where I stand so far.

```
list_a = ["alpha", "beta", "romeo", "nano", "charlie"]
list_b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
from random import shuffle
list_a.append(list_b)
shuffle(list_a)
print(list_a)

for idx, val in enumerate(list_a, start=1):
    print(idx, val)
```

Output

```
['nano', 'charlie', 'alpha', 'beta', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 'romeo']

1 nano
2 charlie
3 alpha
4 beta
5 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
6 romeo
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what output you expect

Comment: I am expecting to see elements of list_b also get shuffled and then enlisted in numeric order. Expected result as an example >>[7,1,3,4,5,2,6] and then enumerate function should show 1-nano 2-charlie 3-alpha 4-beta 5-7 6-1 7-3 and so on so forth. Hope this clarifies

Answer (score 2):

I may be missing something, but you can just shuffle `list_b` before appending it to `list_a`:

```
from random import shuffle

list_a = ["alpha", "beta", "romeo", "nano", "charlie"]
list_b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

shuffle(list_b)

list_a.append(list_b)
shuffle(list_a)
print(list_a)

for idx, val in enumerate(list_a, start=1):
    print(idx, val)
```

Outputs

```
['alpha', 'charlie', 'nano', [1, 4, 5, 2, 7, 3, 6], 'beta', 'romeo']
1 alpha
2 charlie
3 nano
4 [1, 4, 5, 2, 7, 3, 6]
5 beta
6 romeo
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
# append
from random import sample, shuffle
list_a.append(list_b)

# shuffle the list within the list
for i, v in enumerate(list_a): 
     if isinstance(v, list):
          list_a[i] = sample(v, len(v))

# shuffle the list
list_a = sample(list_a, len(list_a))

# unpack elements
list_c = []
for e in list_a:
    if not isinstance(e, list):
        list_c.append(e)
        continue
    for v in e: 
        list_c.append(v)

# print
for i, v in enumerate(list_c): 
    print(i, v)
```

Comment: Feel free to upvote, and use my answer as dedicated answer for your question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get your result by basic concept `if-else` AND `type` method. I have added 2 lines in your code:-

```
list_a = ["alpha","beta","romeo","nano","charlie"]
list_b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
from random import shuffle
list_a.append(list_b)
shuffle(list_a)
print(list_a)
print()

for idx, val in enumerate(list_a, start=1):
    if type(val) is list:   # This is newly added.
        shuffle(val)
        print(idx, val)
    else:   
        print(idx, val)
```

I hope it may help you.